# Migrate to PackageReference Missing Nuget Build Failure

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget, packagereference

I have a Xamarin Forms Project - the Android project targets API 28 (Pie) and uses packages.config for the nuget references.  All of the packages have a targetFramework="monoandroid90".  The project compiles and runs correctly.

I want to migrate to using PackageReference, so I use the Migrate packages.config to PackageReference option.

After this completes I try to build the project and receive an error regarding a missing package:

Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.28.0.0.1

Looking in the packages folder, I can see that none of the Xamarin.Android.Support packages have been downloaded and I can't get them to download - even by reinstalling the package.

I also noticed that the csproj file reference monoandroid81 for all the nugets, even though the packages.config used monoandroid90

Has anyone had a similar difficulty after migrating?

Comment: Try to make `clean rebuild` - delete all `obj` and `debug` directories, and rebuild your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've already tried that, also deleted the packages folder - the project still won't build

Comment: sorry, don't know else of how to solve the problem. If it is so bad, you can create new project with the last nuget updates, and ctrl+c ctrl+v your code, but that's really painfull :)

Comment: That could be an option! I’ve had the same problem with another projects - maybe some other packages need updated - either way it’s not a big problem